# Divs should not overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem. The webpage I'm working on has three areas:

- On the left a navigation, which should always be on the left side
- A content area in the middle, which should always be in the middle of the browser
- The logo area on the right side, which should always be in the top right corner

Here's the code I have right now:

**CSS**

```css
html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
        min-height:100%;
        padding: 0em;
        margin: 0em;
    }

body 
{
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #616a71;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

div#navigation
{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

div#content
{
    position: relative;
    width: 1014px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

div#right
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 258px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>header</title>
    <link href="/style/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        nav
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        logo
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I resize the browser, the content area goes behind the navigation are. What I want to achieve, is that when there is too little space to display the navigation and content area side by side the horizontal scrollbar of the browser should appear.

Comment: I think you have to look into CSS media queries.

Comment: Your width's are huge. Right now you have the entire width of the page at 1492px. Not sure anyone is going to have a screen that size.

Comment: For those wanting to help: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2J5h/)

Comment: @Keith: the current 21.5" iMac has 1920 horizontal pixels. (The 15" MacBook Pro has 1440.)

Comment: @Keith: I'm aware of that, since that page will be only available on the intranet and we have 24'' screen with a resolution of 1920x1200 thats no problem

Comment: Your screen might be fine, but most users won't have that same resolution. So just keep in mind about the rest of the world, unless this is only for your benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the CSS media queries as the ones specifies below

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 // Your code goes here
}
```

You can specify the CSS to be used for these widths. Change the width accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respone. I added the following code to the bottom of my css file, which seems to work quite good

@media (max-width: 1528px)
{
div#content
{
margin-left: 240px;
}

div#right
{
left: 1250px;
top: 0;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the width of divs as %.

```
div#navigation
{
    width: 20%;
}

div#content
{
    width: 60%;
}

div#right
{
    width: 20%;
}
```

and float them all to left.